# Masking Threshold in psychoacoustics model

Tags: audio-processing, psychoacoustics

I am trying to calculate masking threshold using power spectral density but is is given in the attached document that global masking threshold is the sum of individual masking threshold and threshold in quiet.Why we are adding threshold in quiet??

http://103.71.168.43:81/mis/files/coursefiles/AY2018%20-%202019/ECE/AP5074/cf~Masking~69~AP50741542606821-1.pdf

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a link to this publication that does not point to a web server on a non-standard port (81) and that is only known by its IP address please?